# Poststratification and estimation

Tags: estimation, sampling, poststratification

I have a dataset about corn farmers in a certain region with informations like farm size, mean cost per planted hectare, number of employees, etc. Furthermore I also have from another source an estimated value for total corn area in this region.

Suppose that total estimated value is 300,000 acres and I have a sample of 26 farmers that corresponds to 4000 acres. I splitted this data based in the farm size to have more consistent estimations since there is different farmer profiles. Let F be the farm size then

```
Profile1: F <= 100, n1 = 14, Total area = 300 acres
Profile2: F > 100 and F <= 500, n2=10, Total area = 2100 acres
Profile3: F > 500 , n3=2, Total area = 1600 acres
```

Since I have that $300/4000*100=7.5\\%$ of the sampled area is from farmers with area less or equal to 100 acres, is reasonable to say that 22,500 acres(7.5 percent of total area) are from farmers with this profile?